# ODBC connection to MS SQL Server only works woth SECLEVEL 0

Tags: 22.04, openssl, mssql

I am trying to connect to an MS SQL Server from Ubuntu 22.04. I installed the ODBC driver for the MS SQL server, created the DSN, and when I tested the connection using `isql`, I got the error:

> Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server: TCP Provider: Error code 0x2746

Upon further research, I found that this is related to OpenSSL. To get the supported TLS version on the server, I executed `nmap --script ssl-enum-ciphers -p 1433 db.server.com` and in the output, I can see that the server supports TLS 1.2.

The only that worked for me was setting this in the `openssl.cnf` file:

```
MinProtocol = TLSv1_2
CipherString = DEFAULT@SECLEVEL=0
```

If I change the `SECLEVEL` to 1, I again get the same error as above.

Could you please let me know what could be the possible reasons for it to work with SECLEVEL 0 and not with 1?
And is there anything that I need to change on the server to make it work with SECLEVEL 1?

Thank you.